# Jump to next element with keyboard arrows with jQuery

Tags: jquery, keyboard, navigation

I am having a difficult time trying to find my answer on my own, so maybe someone can help.

I have a horizontal scrolling div (wrapper) with mutliple divs (box) inside of it.

I want to be able to click the keyboard arrows keys to jump to the next element.  The window would be scrolling left with each jump.

I've created a basic jsFiddle that people can add too to add keyboard navigation.

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanjay/JjhUN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by storing the positions of the boxes and then testing that against the `window.scrollX` position.  You then animate to the closest box depending on the arrow key pressed.

```
var boxLefts = [];
$('.box').each(function(i, el){
    boxLefts.push(this.offsetLeft);
});

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var dir = false,
        targetLeft = -1;

    switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
        dir = -1;
        break;                
    case 39:
        dir = 1;
        break;
    }

    if (dir) {
        e.preventDefault();
        winLeft = window.scrollX;
        $.each(boxLefts, function(i, v){
            if ((dir == 1 && winLeft < v && targetLeft < 0) ||
                (dir == -1 && winLeft > v)) {
                targetLeft = v;
            }
        });
        if (targetLeft >= 0) {
            $('html, body').animate({scrollLeft: targetLeft}, 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

### [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JjhUN/5/)

Comment: So... I've gotten this to work on my index.html page.  Works perfectly.  But I am running into a problem that I can't figure out.  I am dynamically loading in a new gallery of photos (.box) into a wrapper.  When I do this, and use my arrows for navigation, it jumps to the last image on the next, and back to the first on the prev, skipping EVERYTHING in between.  I tried to just turn it into a function, then call that function on window.load, as well as after loading in the new .html page.  Problem is still there.  Got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

yuuuuuuuuuppppppppppppyyyyyyyyyyyyy got it done finaly.. :)

check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/JjhUN/7/

```
$(function() {
    var index = 0;
    var elems = $('.box');
    var len = $('.box').length;
    elems.eq(index).addClass('selected_div');
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode || e.which;
        switch (key) {
        case 39:
            if(index < len-1){
                elems.eq(index).removeClass('selected_div');
                index = index +1;
                elems.eq(index).addClass('selected_div');
                $('#wrapper').animate({"left": "-=210px"}, "slow");
                }
            break;
        case 37:
            if(index > 0){
              elems.eq(index).removeClass('selected_div');
              index = index - 1;
              elems.eq(index).addClass('selected_div');
              $('#wrapper').animate({"left": "+=210px"}, "slow");
            }
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.selected_div{
    background-color: blue;
}
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```